# What does return x in y and z mean?

Tags: python

I was looking at open AI's gym environment and came across this `def`:

```py
def usable_ace(hand):  # Does this hand have a usable ace?
    return 1 in hand and sum(hand) + 10 <= 21
```

(`hand` is an array of `int`s)

I thought I knew how `in` can be used (Loop example) and what `and` does (Return first if condition is false), but I'm missing something because I can't understand this `return`.

How is the `return` statement evaluated? What's `in hand` used for? Why use `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: I don't understand how the return is statement is evaluated.
What does in hand mean? Why do you need an and there?

Comment: You can evaluate each part of the expression little by little to figure it out… `1 in hand` results in a `True` or `False`, as you presumably know. `sum(...) ...` you presumably understand too, no? It results in a boolean as well. The `and` chains those two expressions and returns `True` if both are `True`, otherwise `False`…

Comment: I understand now, I didnt know that `in` can be used used to find if an element is contained in an array

Comment: @deceze It's etiquette to point to the question I'm duplicating...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267318/476

Comment: @deceze You are completely right, I didn't notice and yes, it's a duplicate. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns True, if hand contains 1 (`x in container` returns True if container contains x, otherwise False) and sum(hand) + 10 <= 21, and it returns False if at least one of these two statements is not True.

What don't you understand? It's simple Boolean algebra.

Comment: I didn't know that `in` could be used to check if an element is contained in an array, I've never seen it used in that way in other languages, makes sense thou.

Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Okay. I'm glad you know understand. Next time try to read documentation.

Comment: I tried, bad lookup